# How to ensure each OpenMP thread has its own copy of thread_local variable in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, openmp, thread-local

I would like to make sure each OpenMP thread in a parallel block has a copy of a `static thread_local` variable. Please consider a code snippet below:

```
#pragma omp parallel
{
    // autodiff tape
    static thread_local stan::math::ChainableStack autodiff_tape;

    #pragma omp for private(i, xparticles_target, xparticles_forward) \
    firstprivate(num_params, Tparams) schedule(static)
    for (i = 0; i < loc_n; i++)
    {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

To do that I start a dedicated `parallel` region and declare the variable `autodiff_tape`. Then I follow up with an `omp for` loop. But I don't see any speed up.

I tried a naive approach of declaring the variable before any OpenMP region and passing it to the loop via `threadprivate` clause:

```
// autodiff tape
static thread_local stan::math::ChainableStack autodiff_tape;

#pragma omp for private(i, xparticles_target, xparticles_forward) \
firstprivate(num_params, Tparams, autodiff_tape) schedule(static)
for (i = 0; i < loc_n; i++)
{
    ...
}
```

But this way I cannot even compile the code. I obtain the following error:

```
error: 'autodiff_tape' is predetermined 'threadprivate' for 'firstprivate'
firstprivate(num_params, Tparams, autodiff_tape) schedule(static)
```

What would be a good way to pass a `static thread_local` variable to a parallel OpenMP loop?

Comment: Are you sure you need a thread local variable? That's is only necessary if those variables carry over from one parallel region to another. Since you're showing only a single parallel region I can't see if this makes sense. If you only need a local copy, then `firstprivate` will do fine. Speedup is a separate issue. Either you need many iterations, or the work per iterations has to be, oh I guess, at least thousands of operations per iteration. Is that the case? How much is your running time anyway?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! I'm not sure. Yes, I don't need these variable to carry over to different parallel regions. I tried `firstprivate`. But I could only see performance benefit for two threads. Using more than two threads still results in the same performance as with two. There is a great potential for many iterations and a long running time. Currently, for a simple test I use 65536 iterations with {2, 4, 8, 16} OpenMP threads. The runtime is ~3 minutes.

Comment: That sounds like enough iterations to get a decent speedup. You're not calling a random number generator, are you?

Comment: No, I'm not. Thank you for your help!

Comment: From my understanding, as the variable has static storage, you don't even need to specify It on OpenMP clauses. All threads have access to it (unless you want to modify It)

Comment: In addition, I don't see how the storage-scope of the variable would impact on scalability. Why do you think that it is related?

Comment: My goal is to ensure each thread has its own variable `autodiff_tape`. It has to be local to a thread. It doesn't have to be shared and accessed by other threads. Consider it a memory buffer required for each thread to do its own autodifferentiation.

On the other hand, it is performance critical for each thread to have its own buffer. Otherwise, this buffer will become a computation bottleneck. Each thread will have to access it to calculate its own autodifferentiation chain.